# Best way to pass through an interface in C++?

Tags: c++, interface

Let's say I have a C++ interface

```
class Iface
{
public:
    virtual ~Iface () {}
    virtual void foo () = 0;
    virtual void bar () = 0;
};
```

And I have some set of classes that needs to expose that on one side and implement it off somewhere else. I find that quite commonly I end up with a bunch of classes in the middle which essentially do something like this:

```
class InTheMiddleSomewhere
    : public Iface // amongst other things
{
public: // Iface
    virtual void foo () { if (impl) impl->foo (); }
    virtual void bar () { if (impl) impl->bar (); }
private:
    IfaceImpl* impl;
};
```

Which gets tiresome to write and maintain as the interfaces expand, proliferate and change.

Q: Is there a better (more or less automatic) way to implement a pass through for a complete interface than coding all that "if (impl) impl->..." stuff by hand?

Comment: Create one class which does it and privately inherit.

Comment: Can `impl` be declared as `Iface*` instead of `IfaceImpl*`?

Comment: @Peter, very good comment, though it only addresses part of the issue. (you still ahve to write it for every method), and has the weakness that some of the in-the-middle classes may want to do slightly different things. What I really want is a "Here's two things that are exactly the same, Bind Them Together *like this*" template/macro/whatever.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, yes it can.

Comment: [AMOP](http://code.google.com/p/amop/wiki/BasicUsage) is a mocking framework which uses some useful techniques for replacing one function call with another. Maybe that would be a route to take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind the call into a function object, and then just pass through the function object (rather than making a delegate call for each member function of the interface).

Consider the following:

```
struct I
{
    virtual R1 f1(A1, B1, ..., Z1) = 0;
    virtual R2 f2(A2, B2, ..., Z2) = 0;
    .
    .
    virtual Rn fn(An, Bn, ..., Zn) = 0;
};
```

Now I have some implementation of I:

```
struct : I
{
    ...
} x, y, z;
```

So I can call x, y and zs function like:

```
Ri xri = x.fi(ai, bi, ..., zi);
Ri yri = y.fi(ai, bi, ..., zi);
Ri zri = z.fi(ai, bi, ..., zi);
```

or I can bind a call to a method of the I interface as follows:

```
function<Ri(I&)> g = bind(&I::fi, _1, ai, bi, ..., zi);
```

and then later:

```
Ri xri = g(x);
Ri yri = g(y);
Ri zri = g(z);
```

This works even if x, y and z are different classes, as long as they are derived from I.

Comment: How would it work precisely, could you expand? Presumably InTheMiddle doesn't implement Iface anymore? after that?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is one downside to using handle classes (Pimpl idiom).  Is there an absolute need to keep compile times down in support of breaking the open/closed principle?  Usually with today's compilers and CPUs, the Pimpl idiom isn't used as much as it used to be.

Comment: The idiom is also used for shared libraries so the implementation can change but retain the same interface. This is essential for compatibility.